# Using java.awt.Robot in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, awt, awtrobot, tetris

I'm working on a (virtual) competitive automated tetris player.

Since the game is, well, competitive, I would naturally like my tetris player to press as many keys as possible at the same time. The solution I have come up with is to devote a thread to each kind of keypress (that way, if two of the same key gets sent, there is a delay, as they are on the same thread. But if two seperate keys get sent, their threads also execute separately, causing both keys to be pressed at the same time).

But due to the multithreading, I am worried that java.awt.Robot is not Thread safe (and googles/SO searches result in no information on the subject). I'd like to avoid creating locks on the Robot object I am using -- If I do that, the entire system becomes pointless (as there would then not be multiple keypresses at the same time, each one would come right after the other).

One possibility is maybe using multiple Robots at the same time (One for each thread), but I am not so sure that they would not simply conflict with each other.

So, how can I deal with a Robot object in a multithreaded environment, so that multiple actions can be executed at the same time?

Comment: can you look into Executors ? [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). Maybe Executors will be of help here.

Comment: Using a single thread to make all the key presses executes extremely fast.  Are you playing against another computer player?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben Actually the bot is playing against real players over the internet -- I am using Java.Robot to control my computer, and because of this fact, there needs to be more delay between keys of the same type, than between keys of different types. This means that if I devote a thread to each type of key, each thread can individually manage its delays, without worrying at all about the delays needed for other keys.

Comment: @gansai Executors look pretty cool! However it seems they are specifically useful for thread management -- they don't deal with my issues in using Robot from multiple threads :(